# ExpressJS oauth2 with passport and oauth2orize

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

This is my first expressJS try ;)

I'm trying to implemente an oauth2 server (password workflow) with passport and oauth2orize.

I use httpie (on mac) to test the connection.

From the server console i have:

```
info: [bin/www] Listening on port 1234
POST /oauth/token - - ms - -
```

From the test client i have:

```
http: error: Request timed out (30s).
```

I push an example to github.

Install:

```
node --version -> v6.1.0
npm install
node dataGen.js
npm start
```

Test command:

```
http POST localhost:1234/oauth/token grant_type=password client_id=mobileV1 client_secret=abc123456 username=andrey password=simplepassword
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the mangoose.connect ;)